# Winforms list to datagridview but no content

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, vsto, outlook-addin

I need a little help using winforms.

I have a datagridview and in code behind I set its datasource:

```
public ContactExporter(IEnumerable<ContactItem> contacts)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingList<ContactItem> contactItems = new BindingList<ContactItem>(contacts.ToList());
    contactsGrid.DataSource = contactItems;
}
```

ContactItem documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867603.aspx

I have three columns with the `DataPropertyNames` `LastName`, `FirstName` and `CompanyName`, but every single cell is empty (rows are existing).

Comment: please show ContactItem class in here. I need to see it before I can give you suggestion

Comment: Can you show us some code too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ContactItem and _ContactItem are interfaces belong to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook. You cannot use them to binding data on DataGridView.

**Solution:**

Create a Class with such properties that you need to show on DataGridView. Then, you wrap ContactItem by that Class.

```
public class MyContactItem : ContactItem
{
    public string MyFirstName { get{ return FirstName;} }
    ...
}
```